# People I'm following via API

Tags: 2013

In SharePoint 2013 there is a list "People I'm following" (usually under `http://MyServer/MyPeople.aspx`). Is this a list, that I can access via Object Model? I would need to write piece of code (from Visual Studio), where I could access who I'm following and who is following me, and change who I'm following - all that trough API or OM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSDN has a code sample of how to do exactly what you want to do: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163133.aspx#bkmk_GetFollowednFollowers.  You can do this both with the server object model and the client object model.